# Distribution of a subset and its parent

Tags: r, sampling, simulation

We have a worldwide distribution (A) of number of friends (e.g. ~Poisson or in my case an empirical one); we also have a subset which gives the distribution (B) of number of friends for country X. In my case, B has smaller mean and variance.

What would be the distribution of the part that constitute the differences between the two?

Practical example: I have 1000 simulated peoples who give the distribution B. I want to add randomly to each people certain numbers of friends to resemble the distribution A. Where to sample these numbers with what probability?

Comment: Why would you do that? These 1000 people are who they are and you cannot change them. Why not sample 1000 people from A instead? If you insist on doing what you asked about, sample 1000 people from A, subtract them from the 1000 in B and add back the differences - you will get the distribution of A. Statistically this is meaningless - you cannot subtract populations.

Comment: @Zahava this is a simulation, we can change anything we want. Sampling from A is not the question at all. And you are right: subtracting is obviously wrong, I did not suggest that; that's why I asked.